# Addition on dynamic form fields

Tags: javascript

I have a form that allows a user to add their past employers. The user can push a button and dynamically add a new employer.

Here is what I need to do: Let's say the user adds 2 employers. I need to first add the number of years spent on each job -

EX: Employer 1 - 2005 - 2007 = 2 years. 
     Employer 2 - 2010 - 2015 = 5 year.

Now, I need to total both EX: 7 years.

The form fields are named like the following:

ID1_empAppWorkHistoryStartDateYear
ID1_empAppWorkHistoryEndDateYear

ID2_empAppWorkHistoryStartDateYear
ID2_empAppWorkHistoryEndDateYear

How do I loop over the dynamic input names in JavaScript and calculate the total number of years sent on all jobs (there can be up to 5)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What if you just store the entered values in variables at input time; you might need a function triggered by an **HTML form event**?. 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

At submit time, if not earlier, you could calculate the difference and add it to whatever place you store the total of years :).

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that you'll name every added input as the following form:

For the first input:

```
IDX_empAppWorkHistoryStartDateYear
```

For the second input:

```
IDX_empAppWorkHistoryEndDateYear
```

Where `X` is the number of the input.

You should firstly add a global variable which will contain the number of inputs added (it will be incremented every time the user add an employer), let's name it `glbInputsNumber`

Your code would be as follow:

```
var totalYears = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < glbInputsNumber; i++) {
totalYears += parseInt(document.getElementsByName('IDX_empAppWorkHistoryEndDateYear'.replace('X', i)).value) - parseInt(document.getElementsByName('IDX_empAppWorkHistoryStartDateYear'.replace('X', i)).value);
}
```

**Edit:** If you're not okay with the global variable, you can use a commun class name to all those inputs, so you can get the number of added inputs as the following:

```
var myobject = document.getElementsByClassName('dateInput');//'dateInput' is the name of class that will be attributed to those added inputs
var inputsNumber = myobject.length / 2;
```

Comment: Do I add the code you provided to an onchange function? I don't know the full syntax

Comment: See my edit, you will be no longer in need of tracking the inputs when they're added.

Comment: Also where do I declare glbInputsNumber. Do you mind posting a full example?

Comment: As I said before, you're not in need of that global variable if you used the method described in the edit.
Concerning the full example, I can't give it because you didn't provide a full explanation of how are you going to use the code that I provided.

Comment: I don't think this will work. Because I am not just adding them all, I am adding (endYear1-startYear1) +  (endYear2-startYear2) + (endYear3-startYear3) and so on.

Comment: Here is what I have so far. It's working with the very first set of form fields:  
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatesum() {
document.submitApp.sum.value =
(document.submitApp.ID1_empAppWorkHistoryEndDateYear.options[document.submitApp.ID1_empAppWorkHistoryEndDateYear.selectedIndex].text-0) -
(document.submitApp.ID1_empAppWorkHistoryStartDateYear.options[document.submitApp.ID1_empAppWorkHistoryStartDateYear.selectedIndex].text-0);
}
</script>